# I can't understand how the logic flow of this ES6 higher-order function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, higher-order-functions

> how the logic flows at: (books) => (shelf) => ...

```
const shelf1 = [
  { name: "name1", shelf: "a" },
  { name: "name2", shelf: "a" },
];
const shelf2 = [
  { name: "name3", shelf: "b" },
  { name: "name4", shelf: "b" },
];
const allBooks = [...shelf1, ...shelf2];

const filter = (books) => (shelf) => books.filter((b) => b.shelf === shelf);

const filterBy = filter(allBooks);
const booksOnShelf = filterBy("b");
```

i need a more verbose equivalent to this shortened expression, to help me to digest that magic

Comment: Here's the re-written version which is more readable: `(books) => { return (shelf) => books.filter(...) }`

Comment: @Yousaf 
Thanks, for help
also, is there a more clear syntax for the call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a function that accepts a `books` argument and returns a *new* function that accepts a `shelf` argument. That function is assigned to `filterBy`, and the result of calling *that* function (an array) is assigned to `booksOnShelf`.

The inner function maintains a reference to `books` when it's returned, and is generally called [a closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

```js
const shelf1=[{name:"name1",shelf:"a"},{name:"name2",shelf:"a"}],shelf2=[{name:"name3",shelf:"b"},{name:"name4",shelf:"b"}];

const allBooks = [...shelf1, ...shelf2];

function filter(books) {
  return function (shelf) {
    return books.filter(function (b) {
      return b.shelf === shelf;
    });
  };
}

// `filter` returns a new function which
// is assigned to `filterBy`. That function accepts
// a `shelf` argument
const filterBy = filter(allBooks);

// The result of calling that new function with
// argument 'b' is assigned to `booksOnShelf`
const booksOnShelf = filterBy('b');

console.log(booksOnShelf);
```